# CPP - Automatically remove #ifdef's and #ifndef's

Tags: c++, ide

I am using Geany IDE and I'm trying to get rid of all the **#ifdef's and #ifndef's** in my code. There are more than 1000 occurrences, they are nested and it is impossible to do it manually.

Here is an example:

```
#define EXPLAIN

#ifndef EXPLAIN
...
#endif
...
#ifdef EXPLAIN
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Somewhere the condition is **#ifdef** and somewhere it is **#ifndef**. You got the idea... Is there an easy way to get rid of them with all the corresponding code?

I will download and install any other software if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "get rid of"? Just get rid of the preprocessor directives, or actually preprocess the file with a specific setting for the macro?

Comment: @KerrekSB I want to remove these parts of the code. Just to delete them.

Comment: The tricky part is going to be keeping the *include guards*...

Comment: @Galik I just want to remove the dead code based on the checked value. Say, if EXPLAIN is defined - everything inside #ifndef EXPLAIN is a dead code and it will never be proceeded. Just trying to clean the code and delete thousands of lines of unnecessary code.

Comment: I don't know of any existing software, although this might exist. I would create a Perl/Python/<insert your favorite language> script. You must keep track of proper nesting and consider `#else` parts.

Comment: Lets say you have defined EXAPLAIN. Do you want to keep `#define EXPLAIN` and `#ifdef EXPLAIN` and just delete the `#ifndef EXPLAIN` part or do you want to delete all preprocessor directives? Please edit the question to include your last comment and answer to this comment.

Comment: You could simply run the preprocessor, capture the output and paste that into a new file. Of course that won't work so well if you're also using other macros, like `assert`, `va_start` or `offsetof` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution is to run gcc using the `-E` flag which only runs the preprocessor. The following command:

```
gcc -E -D EXPLAIN file.cpp -o file.i
```

Preprocesses file.cpp and outputs file.i which is file.cpp preprocessed with the EXPLAIN macro defined.

Some useful flags if you want to produce an output file that is generally more readable and closer to what an input file would be expected to look like:

- `-D NAME` to define the macro `NAME` with definition 1.
- `-fdirectives-only` to process directives but not macros.
- `-C` to keep comments.
- `-P` to inhibit line markers.

Even with these flags, `#include`s will be replaced with the files you are including preprocessed. You can fix this by simply getting rid of the `#include`s, preprocessing the input file, and then adding the `#include`s in the output file.

Source: [Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC): Preprocessor Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unifdef](https://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/) to achieve this.

> The `unifdef` utility selectively processes conditional C preprocessor
>   `#if` and `#ifdef` directives. It removes from a file both the directives and the additional text that they delimit, while otherwise leaving the
>   file alone.